# Is it possible to grant a privilege on a single domain rather than a whole table?

Tags: mysql

Just for example, given the table "Person"(
Name Varchar,
Code int,
Surname varchar);
and let me create a user:
create user user 1 identified by '....';
can i use the following command?
grant insert on Person.code;

Comment: i guess you want row level privileges?

Comment: yes basically..

Comment: There is a way to implement that with a `VIEW` more or less `CREATE VIEW .... SELECT ... WHERE owner = CURRENT_USER();` and some triggers  read this [article](https://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/)

Comment: but if I use a view, im not actually updating the table in the db, right?

Comment: MySQL supports [updatable /insertable views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html) in some extend

Comment: i could even create a view with data from different tables, and it would still work, correct? im talking about the way you told me before